# Are preferred font sizes in Windows8 going to require a calculator?

Tags: xaml, fonts, windows-8, microsoft-metro, font-size

While looking at some official Windows8/"Metro" material, I see this line of xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Contoso Cookbook" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="26.667" />
```

What?!? A font size of 26.667? I realize this is 2/3rds of 40, and 5/6ths of 32, so maybe there's some conversion thing happening there, but is this going to be the preferred way of setting font sizes, and if so, what are the guidelines for coming up with these seemingly random sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are pre-defined Windows 8 styles, located in your project in `Common\StandardStyles.xaml`. Take those as the standard.

The size you are talking about belongs to `SubheaderTextStyle`.

Here is why you get the "weird" size. If you look at the [typography guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx), you see the values in points. However, in XAML you specify the font size in pixels. Sample to go with:  96 PPI (pixel-per-inch) display. In 1 inch, you get 72 points. Doing simple math:

```
96 pixels per inch / 72 points per inch = 1.(3) pixels/point
```

So, `26.667 / 1.(3) ~ 20pt`

This way, you are getting a consistent font size.

Comment: Ah, so the preferred font sizes in Win8 will be - in xamlese - 56 (for 42 points), 26.667 (for 20 points), 14.667 (for 11 points), and 12 (for 9 points). I reckon this will be a common point of confusion for folks as they specify size both in xaml and in code at times, and have to switch between the two. Not that it's difficult math, but I'm sure I will say to myself: now which one uses points, and which ones pixels again?

Comment: That is why you rely on built-in styles :-)

Comment: Blend allows you to specify font sizes in points and automatically converts them to pixels in xaml, eg 8pt = 10.667px and 18pt = 24px, shame visual studio missed on that.