# How to let controls maintain position after Window size changes

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I am creating a Windows Store app, using XAML and C#.

If for example I run my application on the Windows Simulator (tablet), the layout is perfect.  When I run my application on my local machine, the layout does not at all look like what it looks on the simulator.

How do I design my application to fit both perfectly?

Should I have multiple designs, and with start up check screen resolution and choose the layout best suited for that resolution?

Basically, how do I make sure my app will always look its best, no matter on what screen size it my run out there in the real world?

I am currently making use of a Grid for the layout of the controls, 3 columns, and 3 rows, with the Width and Height set to "*".  I understand that with larger screen sizes, the column width and row heights will increase, and the opposite for smaller screen sizes.

I am basically just looking for good design practices, as to always try best and avoid massive layout changes.

Comment: Please view my edit above, if my post is more clear now. I am not looking for help with my current code layout, basically just looking for guidelines as to avoid this happening?  If you still prefer code examples, I will place my code in my post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design Metro UIs with fonts that look good on any resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081221/how-to-design-metro-uis-with-fonts-that-look-good-on-any-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I attended a Microsoft seminar lastly for 2 days. I asked if ViewBox exist for Windows Store Apps. They said "I don't think so" :)

But it exist :D

I'm sure it will be easy with a ViewBox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox

Put your design in a view box. That's all. We use it for silverlight.

Comment: Still new to the whole XAML concept, and not sure what the ViewBox control is all about at the moment, but will definitely have a look now. Thanks