# Why do windows store apps specify scaled assets of 180 and 140 when windows defaults to 125 and 150?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store app and was looking through the Package.appxmanifest when I noticed that all of the different logos have options for a scale of 180%, 140%, and most have an 80%.  Why do they have these scales when my Windows 8 Pro tablet only has default scale options of 125% and 150%?

Also, how important are these scaled logos?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design Metro UIs with fonts that look good on any resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081221/how-to-design-metro-uis-with-fonts-that-look-good-on-any-resolution)

Comment: @HansPassant That question is nothing like mine.  It is asking for advice on fonts while I am asking why the scale options on images is the way it is.

Comment: It explains why 140 and 180 were chosen.  Your assumption that DPI is a fixed number and 125% and 150% are the only options is just wrong.  Note the graph, DPI is along the horizontal axis.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not asking why they choose 180% and 140%, I am asking why my tablet has a fixed scaling of 125% and 150% when the VS options are 140% and 180%.  Yes, you can select your own scaling, but the default options are 100%, 125%, and 150%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research it has become clear that the scaling I was referring to (100%, 125%, and 150%) are **desktop** scaling (which affect the desktop and applications running on it) and do not affect the scaling of Windows Store apps.