# Add a Resolution / ScaleFactor to the Visual Studio 2013 Devices Panel

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In Visual Studio 2013 on the Device Panel how do you add a Resolution and Scale Factor to the Display drop down? I assume it would also be the same for Blend. It seems to be missing the Surface Pro 3 Resolution/Scale Factor.

[image: VS 2013 Device Panel]

Comment: That's not how it works, WinRT apps automatically scale.  To 80, 100, 140 or 180%, numbers you'll recognize from the Visual Assets tab in the package manifest.  Surface Pro 3 has a 2160 x 1440 display, an oddball 3:2 aspect ratio with 216 dpi that you are unlikely to find in the emulator.  Just pick the closest match, you ought to get 140% scaling if [this graph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15081850/17034) is accurate.

Comment: I was not under any misconception that this would have any effect on my app when compiled/published. Since I was specifically targeting a Surface Pro 3 for an enterprise scenario I wanted to easily preview that size while in the design view. I do appreciate your comments though.